# autoclass and instance attributes

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

According to the [sphinx documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute), the `.. autoattribute` directive should be able to document instance attributes. However, if I do::

```
.. currentmodule:: xml.etree.ElementTree

.. autoclass:: ElementTree

   .. autoattribute:: ElementTree._root
```

Then when building I get an AttributeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):etree.ElementTree.ElementTree                 
  File "/Volumes/Raptor/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 326, in import_object
    obj = self.get_attr(obj, part)
  File "/Volumes/Raptor/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 232, in get_attr
    return safe_getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
  File "/Volumes/Raptor/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sphinx/util/inspect.py", line 70, in safe_getattr
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _root
```

even though if I instantiate `ElementTree` and try and access the `_root` attribute, it works fine::

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
>>> e = ElementTree()
>>> hasattr(e, '_root')
True
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm actually having this issue with one of my own classes, but am just using the ElementTree class as an example since it's in the standard library)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in the way non-public instance attributes are handled. Sphinx is supposed to be able to recognize [instance attributes defined in `__init__`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/280).

I can't say how this should be fixed. There is an open bug report that seems to be related: [Non-public instance attributes are not documented without __slots__](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/956).

If the following line is added to the definition of the `ElementTree` class in ElementTree.py,

```
__slots__  = ["_root"]
```

then the `AttributeError` that you get goes away.

Comment: Confirmed for me too. Any idea if this was fixed and if so, what version?

Comment: The linked bug report was closed on May 30, 2019.