# Instance attribute error

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to `.. autoclass::` a class with instance attribute:

```
.. autoclass:: synergine.core.Test.Test
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :private-members:
```

of (in file synergine/core/Test.py):

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        #: A foo bar instance attribute !
        self._foo = 'bar'
```

But when i `make html` sphinx raise this error:

```
/home/bux/Projets/synergine/doc/source/Components.rst:143: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import attribute 'Test._foo' from module 'synergine.core.Test'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sphinx/util/inspect.py", line 108, in safe_getattr
    return getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute '_foo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 342, in import_object
    obj = self.get_attr(obj, part)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 241, in get_attr
    return safe_getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sphinx/util/inspect.py", line 114, in safe_getattr
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _foo
```

Why ? What i've to do to document this instance attribute ?

**Edit: Seems to be bug reported: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/956 . Any way to hack it ?**

Comment: Seems to be bug reported: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/956 . Any way to hack it ?

Comment: A way to "hack it" that might work is to add `__slots__ = ['_foo']` to the definition of the `Test` class (similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11347883/407651).

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in the previous comment?

Comment: Not yet, i try when i can and notify you here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is still there!
I had the issue when I wanted to create an in-house developer documentation.
Therefore I also wanted the private-protected variables and class constants be documented.

### Example:

```py
class Foo(object):
    #: foo is a list for ...
    __foo = []
    __bar = None
    """
    bar stores ...
    """
    # [...]
```

### Solution:

in `sphinx.util.inspect` change the function `safe_getattr`:

```py
def safe_getattr(obj, name, *defargs):
    """A getattr() that turns all exceptions into AttributeErrors."""
    try:
        if name.startswith("__") and not name.endswith("__"): # <-+ these lines
            obj_name = obj.__name__                           #   | have to be
            if "_%s%s"%(obj_name,name) in obj.__dict__:       #   | added
                name = "_%s%s"%(obj_name,name)                # <-+ 
        return getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
    except Exception as error:
        # this is a catch-all for all the weird things that some modules do
        # with attribute access
        if defargs:
            return defargs[0]
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

this will remove the error.
To remove the internal namespace, of protected class constants in the generated docs, change the function `filter_members` inside `sphinx.ext.autodoc`:

```py
def filter_members(self, members, want_all):
    # [...] 
    for (membername, member) in members:
        # [...]
        elif want_all and membername.startswith('_'):
            # ignore members whose name starts with _ by default
            keep = self.options.private_members and \
                        not membername.startswith('_'+namespace) and\  # <- ADD THIS LINE
                        (has_doc or self.options.undoc_members)    
    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank's, i will test it and go back here when it will done.